# Error saying "Unable to load script. Make sure you're either running a Metro server..."

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

"Unable to load script. Make sure you're either running a Metro server (run 'react-native-start') or that your bundle 'index.android.bundle' is packaged correctly for release."

I am moving my code from Expo CLI to React Native CLI. I am just moving over my assets, components, and js files over and I am adding all the packages to RN CLI as well.

I have been stuck on this for about 10 hrs now and searched up every single error that popped up. I am now finally going through stack overflow now.

[error http://prntscr.com/p0vp49](http://prntscr.com/p0vp49)

I have tried running react-native-start and npm start. I dont know how to go to my bundle 'index.android.bundle' so that might be the problem.

```
import { createAppContainer, createSwitchNavigator } from "react-navigation";
import LogInNavigator from './screens/LogInScreen.js';
import AppNavigator from './screens/MainScreen.js';

//Exporting Navigator
export default createAppContainer(
  createSwitchNavigator(
    {
      loginNav: LogInNavigator,
      mainNav: AppNavigator,
    },
    {
      initialRouteName: "loginNav",
    }
  )
);`
```

I expect a login screen at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you installed all the dependencies correctly?

My Dev dependencies are:

`"babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "babel-jest": "^24.8.0",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^3.2.0",
    "jest": "^24.8.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.53.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.6.3"`

Make sure you add **metro-react-native-babel-preset** and do **npm start**

Comment: Yes it worked. Thank you. Why is that dependency necessary?